# enable button in gridview with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` and in the footer it puts a total value in `grandTotalPCT`. If `grandTotalPCT` is not equal to 100 I want the button `btnUpdatePCTD` to remain disabled, if it does equal 100 then the button is enabled.

The code below is called from another function which works as the `grandTotalPCT` value changes. The problem is the button status does not change.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Line" ItemStyle-Width="50%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblLineD" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("line") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdatePCTD" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm" OnClick="updateDockPCT"  Enabled="False" />
    </FooterTemplate>
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="% Target" ItemStyle-Width="25%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbPTC" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("dailypercent")) * 100 %>' CssClass="tbPTC"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="grandTotalPCT" runat="server" CssClass="grandTotalPCT"></asp:Label>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

//To get grand Total PCT
function CalculateGrandTotalPCT() {
    var grandTotalPCT = 0.0;
    $('#<%=gvDockPCT.ClientID %> tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
        grandTotalPCT = grandTotalPCT + parseFloat($(this).find('.tbPTC').length == 0 || !$(this).find('.tbPTC').val() ? 0 : $(this).find('.tbPTC').val());

    });
    $('#<%=gvDockPCT.ClientID %> .grandTotalPCT').text(grandTotalPCT.toFixed(3));
    if (grandTotalPCT.toFixed(3) == 100.000)
    {
        $('#<%=gvDockPCT.ClientID %> .btnUpdatePCTD').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#<%=gvDockPCT.ClientID %> .btnUpdatePCTD').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `OnRowDataBound` event and not jQuery.

```
    decimal totalValue = 0;

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            totalValue += Convert.ToDecimal(row["tocht_id"]);
        }
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            if (totalValue == 100)
            {
                Button button = e.Row.FindControl("btnUpdatePCTD") as Button;
                button.Enabled = false;
            }

            Label label = e.Row.FindControl("grandTotalPCT") as Label;
            label.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", GridView1.Rows.Count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not counting the rows, I am totaling the value of all the rows. The total is recalculated when the fields is changed using the blur method.

Comment: $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false) works but it disables all buttons.

Comment: You can expand the RowDataBound to include the rows and their values, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the button name to cssclass CssClass="**btnUpdatePCTD** btn btn-default btn-sm"

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdatePCTD" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btnUpdatePCTD btn btn-default btn-sm" OnClick="updateDockPCT"  Enabled="False" />
```